# How can I connect my two Macbook Pros in a master-slave relationship to double my CPU power?

Tags: cpu, macbook

My specific use case is scientific computing. I do a lot of cpu-bound computing on my MacbookPro. It's heavily parallel already. I have access to another identical macbook pro, and if I could somehow connect them I was wondering if I could double the number of available cpu cores for even more concurrency. I mainly code in java, if that matters.

If it is possible, what steps do I need to take?

Comment: How about renting a VPS to do the heavy work?

Comment: HPC clustering is complicated and not something you can just turn on. Perhaps, since you are a programmer, a more Grid-Computing architecture is warranted, where one system distributes work to any system running a client. then you can enroll any number of nodes, and they don;t need to be on similar hardware.

Comment: Have youl looked into xgrid? Alternatively you could try setting up docker containers on both machines to which you distribute the computations, but perhaps that's too much overhead.

Comment: Divide the workload into 2, and run on the 2 computers.

Comment: @mashuptwice I have worked with many cloud compute platforms and would like to avoid the added complexity and $$$ cost

Comment: @FrankThomas I appreciate this thought, thanks. I think you are probably exactly right. And I have never heard the terms HPS clustering or grid-computing so thanks for giving me some things to look up.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke thank you for the xgrid suggestion but I should have mentioned I want to keep it free. And I think your second suggestion is in line with what Frank Thomas said what I'll probably do (have same software on both machines and just have one distribute jobs to both)

Comment: if anyone else ever stumbles across this I just found this nice resource https://images.apple.com/server/docs/High_Performance_Computing_v10.4.pdf which will probably scare you away as it just did for me